# C#, extension method RenderTransform not acccepting a first argument of type "System.Drawing.Rectangle"

Tags: c#, rendertransform

```
private void RemoveUnfitChromosomes()
        {
            int[] buildingLW = new int[2 * buildingNo];     //2x for length & width

            for (int i = 0; i <= 2 * (buildingNo - 1);)        //working values to be changed for user input
            {
                buildingLW[i] = 30;     //l,x
                buildingLW[i + 1] = 10;     //w.y

                i = i + 2;
            }

            foreach (int[] chromosome in population)
            {
                int[] temp = new int[3 * buildingNo];
                List<Rectangle> building = new List<Rectangle>();

                Array.Copy(chromosome, temp, 3 * buildingNo);

                for (int j = 0; j < buildingNo; j++)
                {
                    building[j] = new Rectangle(temp[3 * j] - buildingLW[2 * j] / 2, temp[3 * j + 1] + buildingLW[2 * j + 1] / 2, buildingLW[2 * j + 1], buildingLW[2 * j]);

                    RotateTransform rotate = new RotateTransform();
                    rotate.Angle = temp[j+2];
                    rotate.CenterX = temp[j];
                    rotate.CenterY = temp[j+1];

                    building[j].RenderTransform= rotate;
                }
```

My problem is here **building[j].RenderTransform= rotate;**, which I will have this extension method RenderTransform not accepting a first argument of type "System.Drawing.Rectangle". I understand that the rectangle structure does not have a method for rotation. I am just confused by the information I am having.

The above is my code where I am trying import my data from another part of my code and then rotate my rectangle built from those data. FYI, I am trying to see if any of those rectangles intersection with one another. I am confused with the following code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754009(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2. Their code was able to use **polyline2.RenderTransform**, so is there a way I can do it too?

I have tried searching online for hours, but I'm new to programming and cant understand what people are saying sometimes, so my apologies if the question is repeated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

RenderTransform is not an extension method, it's a property and Rectangle has it as well. **System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle** not *System.Drawing.Rectangle*

Comment: Thanks. I managed to change my rect to a System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle, but now I am unable to use the .IntersectsWith method. Any help? Thank you

Comment: I don't see any IntersectsWith() method . You're probably using Visual Studio so when the cursor is on top of the method press F1 to get the online help for that method